# Save the index value of blanks in a string to a tuple in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I save the index position of spaces in a text sentence to a tuple  so I can reconvert the sentence back after removing the strings?

For example in this text the are spaces which causes an error as there are no space in the ascii alphabet. So I want to remove the spaces, convert and then reformat spaces back to original position.

```
import string

text = "This is the text I wish to convert"

alpha = [c for c in list(string.ascii_lowercase)]
alphaTup = tuple(alpha)

myConvert = list(text.lower())

blanks = myConvert.index(' ')
print(blanks)
# This doesn't work
for item in myConvert:
    #find index of item in alphaTup and return value at index + 1
    newLet = alphaTup[alphaTup.index(item) + 1]
    print(newLet)
```

Comment: can you give us an example about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: space is certainly a valid letter in the standard ascii alphabet ... so not sure what you mean

Comment: @ozgur          Just doing a cipher transform, so take the sentence and convert each word to consist of the next letter in the alphabet. So the word 'this' would be 'uijt'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know the indices of all the blanks, I suppose using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) could be helpful:

```
blank_indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(text) if c == ' ']
```

(This gives a `list` instead of a `tuple`, but it's not hard to get the `tuple` if you really need it...)

With that said, looping over a string character-by-character, is not the best way to accomplish *most* tasks in python.  It's hard for me to tell exactly what transform you're trying to perform on the string, so I'm not sure how to advise better ...